# Using datetime module to set time intervals

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to choose an appointment time from a list of available days of the week. I need help on how to use the `datetime` module to accomplish this instead of what I came up with.

```
avail_days = {'Mon': ['8:00AM', '8:30AM', '9:00AM', '10:00AM', '10:30AM', '11:00AM', '11:30AM', '12:00AM'], 'Tues': ['8:00AM', '8:30AM', '9:00AM', '10:00AM', '10:30AM', '11:00AM', '11:30AM', '12:00AM']}
```

Each appointment should last 30 minutes and available days should be weekdays from 8AM to 12PM.

Comment: Do you need to do some kind of calculation on these times? I don't see any problem with a simple `list` of strings if you just want to keep track of which ones are available.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: I want to be able to find available dates and return it to the user in calendar format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to date ranges, I find [`Delorean`](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package and it's `stops()` function quite useful, readable and convenient. Assuming you want to programmatically generate time ranges for each day between two datetimes, here is a sample implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from delorean import stops
import delorean

start = datetime.today()
stop = datetime.today() + timedelta(7)

for day in stops(freq=delorean.DAILY, start=start, stop=stop):
    start = day.naive().replace(hour=8, minute=0)
    stop = day.naive().replace(hour=12, minute=0)

    for t in stops(freq=delorean.MINUTELY, interval=30, start=start, stop=stop):
        print t.datetime.strftime("%A %H:%M")
```

Prints:

```
Monday 08:00
Monday 08:30
Monday 09:00
Monday 09:30
Monday 10:00
Monday 10:30
Monday 11:00
Monday 11:30
Monday 12:00
Tuesday 08:00
Tuesday 08:30
Tuesday 09:00
Tuesday 09:30
Tuesday 10:00
Tuesday 10:30
Tuesday 11:00
Tuesday 11:30
Tuesday 12:00
Wednesday 08:00
Wednesday 08:30
Wednesday 09:00
Wednesday 09:30
Wednesday 10:00
Wednesday 10:30
Wednesday 11:00
Wednesday 11:30
Wednesday 12:00
...
Sunday 08:00
Sunday 08:30
Sunday 09:00
Sunday 09:30
Sunday 10:00
Sunday 10:30
Sunday 11:00
Sunday 11:30
Sunday 12:00
Monday 08:00
Monday 08:30
Monday 09:00
Monday 09:30
Monday 10:00
Monday 10:30
Monday 11:00
Monday 11:30
Monday 12:00
```